# Problam with full online backup of neo4j version 3.0.3

Tags: neo4j

I'm using neo4j version 3.0.3, enterprise edition. I have problem with online full backup - it hangs always at the same point, during second part (consistency checking?).
When i interrupt this full backup, next i can do incremental backup without any errors.  Database has 82GB. I tried settings:
tools.consistency_checker.check_indexes=false
tools.consistency_checker.check_label_scan_store=false
but it didn't help.

Comment: Consistency checking might consume some time. How long have you waited so far. What was the output until that point?

Comment: Coping files takes about half an hour. Consistency checking hangs on 65% (it means that there is no erros, warnings, simply i see 65% on progress bar) I was waiting to finish it about 8h and it's still hangs, so i interrupted it. Up to me interruption, load on cpu is high and memory is used. I tried to add java options to tune this, but it didn't resolve the issue (JAVA_OPTS="-Xmx44g -XX:ParallelGCThreads=7")

Comment: try to get a treaddump (either via jstack or kill -3) to understand what JVM is doing when reach 65%.

Comment: I did treaddump. There are 36 threads and all have status BLOCKED. Link to dump: http://pastebin.com/ixZd50zB

Comment: I tried to use heap 100GB per backup tool and succeeded.  It looks like consistency checking is working on one thread and needs to  put all database into heap!! Even i setup heap 100GB, gc had a lot of work.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I solved updating Neo4j to the version 3.0.5.

Comment: I upgraded to version 3.0.6 and still have problem with full backup